# While adding an object to the list, constructor is not performed

Tags: c#

I have a 2 lists with 2 other objects. I want to use one function to add both different object to both different lists.

I do the following:

My lists:

```
List<Kelner> kelnerzy = new List<Kelner>();
List<Kasjer> kasjerzy = new List<Kasjer>();
```

My Kasjer class, the second is similar

```
class Kasjer
{
    public Kasjer()
    {
        Free = true;
    }
    public bool Free { get; set; }
}
```

My function, where ilosc=3:

```
private static void Dodaj_do_list<T>(List<T> objects, int ilosc) where T : new()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ilosc; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(new T());
        }
    }
```

And then I just called function and added 2 objects normally like this:

```
Dodaj_do_list(kasjerzy, 3);
kasjerzy.Add(new Kasjer());
kasjerzy.Add(new Kasjer());
```

Display function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kasjerzy.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kasjerzy[i].Free);
}
```

I expect the output like this:

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

But the actual output is:

```
False
False
False
True
True
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I get 5x True ....   https://dotnetfiddle.net/GpATDg

Comment: I also dded a demo

Comment: Something else is changing your data here. As well as @shingo I cannot reproduce your problem. If I write the output loop immediately after adding the elements, I get True five times.

Comment: try removing public setter from Kasjer object on Free property, the build will fail somewhere, and that will be your problem. `public bool Free {get; private set;}`

Comment: Problem solved, there was some mess in the code